# How to handle the exception "An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Delete Resource' " thorugh program

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I need to handle an exception("An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Delete Resource'") through program.

I am getting this exception while deleting IProject using Delete menu from eclipse. Because another windows process is using one of the resource in my IProject.

So instead of eclipse warning window i need to display my own warning message to describe clearly.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the type of error, I'll advice your catch exception statement should just contain (Exception object). that's what I use on Netbeans IDE, I don't know if it works for such error on eclipse

Comment: It is throwing ResourceException.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to deal with this error after it happens is likely to leave the project in a mess.

Instead if you have a way of detecting that the error will occur you could use the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` extension point to add a delete participant which can reject the delete in the `checkConditions` method.

Comment: Hi greg, can you please provide me step by step process (or) snapshot about how to implement above specified extension point. Because i am new to xtext stuff.

Comment: A delete participant is a substantial piece of code and I don't have one to hand.